# Nunit-agent debug workaround

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nunit

I attached to nunit-agent.exe about 49 times today, and my fingers are getting tired.  I was wondering if there is an automated way to get the nunit-agent.exe attach to the debugger within Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed my nunit.exe.config file based on the instructions on [this page](http://frater.wordpress.com/2010/05/04/debugging-nunit-tests-under-visual-studio-2010/).  Worked like a charm.